# How to make bend lines/arrows with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

I've been testing out TikZ lately, but I'm still quite new to it. What I want to do is to create a line to indicate that a parameter belongs to a part of the drawing. For example "This surface that I'm pointing at has temperature T". What I've seen used sometimes is to have a line or arrow with a small S-bend on the middle. I think this is a good idea as it's easy to see that the line doesn't have anything to do with the body you're drawing. Unfortunatley I had some problems finding a picutre explaining what I'm thinking of. The arrow specifying P<sub>θ</sub> on [this](http://www.gear-net.com/report/image/rep03-03.gif) picture was the best I could find allthough it's not completly the same.

Is there any easy way to do something like this in TikZ? I have no idea what it would be called...

Comment: How about [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/clusters-of-atoms/)? or [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/swan-wave-model/)? in general is the `to[out=90,in=180]` keyword you are looking for, I think.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this in TikZ.  Here are three examples:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) (text) {This is some text.};
  \node[anchor=west] at (3,1) (description) {Here is the description.};
  \draw (description) edge[out=180,in=0,->] (text);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) (text) {This is some text.};
  \node[anchor=west] at (3,1) (description) {Here is the description.};
  \draw[->] (description) -| (text);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) (text) {This is some text.};
  \node[anchor=west] at (3,1) (description) {Here is the description.};
  \draw[->] (description) .. controls ([xshift=-4cm] description) and ([xshift=4cm] text) .. (text);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces

[image: Screenshot of the three TikZ pictures.]

Comment: Brilliant! That actually don't look too difficult :)

Comment: The last one can be done much more easily using the line `\draw[->] (description) to [out = 180, in = 0, looseness = 2] (text);`.  The `looseness` parameter sets the controls automatically and is more intuitive.

Comment: @RyanReich: True.  My motivation for including that last example was to demonstrate TikZ's lower level Bézier curve drawing capabilities.

Comment: Which package of Tikz are you using?

Comment: @Daniel I don't recall what version I used when I posted this answer, but these commands are all supported in the core TikZ/PGF engine and have been for years (if not all along).  A vanilla install of any modern LaTeX distro should be able to compile this example directly out of the box, and I can confirm that that is the case for both TexLive and MacTeX.

Comment: I asked since it didn't work for me in MikTeX for windows, so I though it might be not from the core package ...