# Curved connector ends with arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make bend lines/arrows with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/how-to-make-bend-lines-arrows-with-tikz)

I draw arrows in TikZ often by that:

```
\draw [->] (begin_point.south) -- ++(0,-4) -| (end_point.north);
```

Now I would like to make the arrows more fluent like the figure shows, could anyone tell me how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Possible `\draw [->] (begin_point.south) to [out=-90,in=90] (end_point.north);` or with `.. controls ..`

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/how-to-make-bend-lines-arrows-with-tikz help you?

Comment: yes it's a duplicated question