# How to make "L" shaped arrows with curved edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I simplified this example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/how-to-make-bend-lines-arrows-with-tikz), however what I am looking is an "L" shaped arrow that curves when it gets to the same height as A which can be seen in the below figure. The red curve is the one that I want.

[image]

Here is the code that I have right now for the black arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) (text) {A};
  \node[anchor=west] at (5,5) (description) {B};
  \draw (description) edge[out=180,in=0,->] (text);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `rounded corners` to the path properties. You can control this by setting a value.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) (text) {A};
  \node[anchor=west] at (5,5) (description) {B};
  \draw[rounded corners=10pt](description) |- (text);
  \draw[red, rounded corners=25pt](description) |- (text);
  \draw[green, rounded corners=50pt](description) |- (text);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And can I use this to make the line to fold more than once?

Comment: @Naji, sure you can. E.g., try `\draw[rounded corners=10pt, ->] (description) |- ($(description)!.5!(text)$) |- (text);` (and to not forget `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the preamble).

Comment: @Naji Sorry for my late answer, it was night time here when you asked me. I see someone else helped you though. :)

Comment: @Alenanno, also it was 2AM here but I am quite a night owl! :)
Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Naji My pleasure!

Answer (score 8):

You could use control points for this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[<-] (0,0) .. controls (4,0) and (5,1) .. (5,5);
\draw[<-,dashed] (0,0) .. controls (4.5,0) and (5,0.5) .. (5,5);
\draw[<-,dotted] (0,0) .. controls (4.9,0) and (5,0.1) .. (5,5);
  \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) (text) {A};
  \node[anchor=west] at (5,5) (description) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Take a look at the pgfmanual for more on control points. Basically: `(s) .. controls (c1) and (c2) .. (e)` draws a line starting at (s), ending at (e), with an initial tangent heading (c1) and a final tangent heading toward (c2).

Here how far (c1) was from (s) controlled how soon the path started to curve, and similarly for (c2) & (e).

[image]

Comment: What are control points for exactly?
Plus, what I want is to be straight until the curved edge, and not to have the curve in the whole arrow.

Comment: @Naji I added a bit of an explanation. Control points are good for drawing curved paths with specified tangents / endpoints. You can control how soon the path curves by the position of the control points. That said, Alenanno's approach looks a lot easier.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,90},PointSymbol=none](0,0){A}(4,3){B}
    \ncangle[angleB=-90,linearc=2]{<-}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Animated version

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\multido{\n=.0+.5}{7}{%
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,90},PointSymbol=none](0,0){A}(4,3){B}
    \ncangle[angleB=-90,linearc=\n]{<-}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cmhughes: How do you know? Thanks.

Comment: Look at your profile, and check out how many votes you have by `tikz`- it's your highest tag :)