# How to bend an edge over the other nodes and edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I try to create something like this

[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{operator}=[circle, radius=0.2cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick, ->, >=stealth]
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]

\node(A0)[operator] {$A_0$}; 
\node(A1)[operator, below of = A0] {$A_1$}; 
\node(A2)[operator, below of = A1] {$A_2$}; 

\node(B0)[operator, right of = A0, xshift=2cm] {$B_0$}; 
\node(B1)[operator, below of = B0] {$B_1$}; 
\node(B2)[operator, below of = B1] {$B_2$}; 

\node(C0)[operator, right of = B0, xshift=2cm] {$C_0$}; 
\node(C1)[operator, below of = C0] {$C_1$}; 
\node(C2)[operator, below of = C1] {$C_2$}; 

\node(p1) [above of = B0] {};
\node(p2) [above of = A0] {};

\draw (A0) edge[out=0, in=180,arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{3D} (B1);
\draw (A1) edge[out=0, in=180,arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{3D} (B2);
\draw (A2) edge[out=0, in=180,arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{4D} (B0);

\draw (B0) edge[out=0, in=180,arrow] (C2);
\draw (B1) edge[out=0, in=180,arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{D} (C0);
\draw (B2) edge[out=0, in=180,arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{D} (C1);

\draw (C0) edge[out=40, in=0,arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{6D} (A2);
\draw (C1) edge[out=40, in=0,arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{7D} (A0);
\draw (C2) edge[out=180, in=0,arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{7D} (A1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And so the result is

[image]

I can't figure out how to connect properly the C nodes with the A nodes. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

Something similar to your first image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,calc}

\tikzstyle{operator}=[circle, radius=0.2cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick, ->, >=stealth]
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
\node(A0)[operator] {$A_0$}; 
\node(A1)[operator, below of = A0] {$A_1$}; 
\node(A2)[operator, below of = A1] {$A_2$}; 

\node(B0)[operator, right of = A0, xshift=2cm] {$B_0$}; 
\node(B1)[operator, below of = B0] {$B_1$}; 
\node(B2)[operator, below of = B1] {$B_2$}; 

\node(C0)[operator, right of = B0, xshift=2cm] {$C_0$}; 
\node(C1)[operator, below of = C0] {$C_1$}; 
\node(C2)[operator, below of = C1] {$C_2$}; 

\node(p1) [above of = B0] {};
\node(p2) [above of = A0] {};
%%%%
\draw[arrow] (A0) -- node[pos=0.5, above]{3D} (B1);

\draw[arrow] (A1) -- node[pos=0.5, above]{3D} (B2);
\draw[arrow] (A2) -- node[pos=0.5, above]{4D} (B0);

\draw[arrow] (B0) -- (C2);
\draw[arrow] (B1) -- node[pos=0.5, above]{D} (C0);
\draw[arrow] (B2) -- node[pos=0.5, above]{D} (C1);

\draw[arrow, rounded corners=5mm] (C0) -- ($(C0.-45) + (0.5,-0.5)$) -- ($(C2.-45) + (0.5,-0.5)$)  -- ($(A2.-45) + (0.5,-0.5)$)  -- node[pos=0.5, below]{6D} (A2); 
\draw[arrow, rounded corners=5mm] (C1) -- ($(C1.45) + (0.5,0.5)$) -- ($(C0.45) + (0.5,0.5)$)  -- ($(A0.45) + (0.5,0.5)$)  -- node[pos=0.5, above]{7D} (A0); 
\draw[arrow, rounded corners=6mm] (C2) -- ($(C2.45) + (0.7,0.7)$) -- ($(C0.45) + (0.7,0.7)$)  -- ($(A0.135) + (-0.7,0.7)$)  -- ($(A1.135) + (-0.7,0.7)$)  -- node[pos=0.5, anchor=north east]{7D} (A1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the `looseness` option. From the TikZ documentation:

> /tikz/looseness=<number>
>
> This number specifies how “loose” the curve will be. In detail, the following happens: TikZ computes the distance between the start and the target coordinate (if the start and/or target coordinate are nodes, the distance is computed between the points on their border). This distance is then multiplied by a fixed factor and also by the factor <number>. The resulting distance, let us call it d, is then used as the distance of the control points from the start and target coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{operator}=[circle, radius= 0.2 cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow}= [thick, ->, >=stealth]
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =1.5 cm ]

\node(A0)[operator] {$A_0$}; 
\node(A1)[operator, below of = A0] {$A_1$}; 
\node(A2)[operator, below of = A1] {$A_2$}; 

\node(B0)[operator, right of = A0, xshift=2cm] {$B_0$}; 
\node(B1)[operator, below of = B0] {$B_1$}; 
\node(B2)[operator, below of = B1] {$B_2$}; 

\node(C0)[operator, right of = B0, xshift=2cm] {$C_0$}; 
\node(C1)[operator, below of = C0] {$C_1$}; 
\node(C2)[operator, below of = C1] {$C_2$};

\draw (A0) edge[out=0, in=180, arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{3D} (B1);
\draw (A1) edge[out=0, in=180, arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{3D} (B2);
\draw (A2) edge[out=0, in=180, arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{4D} (B0);

\draw (B0) edge[out=0, in=180, arrow] (C2);
\draw (B1) edge[out=0, in=180, arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{D} (C0);
\draw (B2) edge[out=0, in=180, arrow] node[pos=0.85, above]{D} (C1);

\draw (C0) edge[out=-63, in=-20, arrow, out looseness=2.6, in looseness=1.5] node[pos=0.85, below]{6D} (A2);
\draw (C1) edge[out=40, in=20, arrow, out looseness=1.5] node[pos=0.85, above]{7D} (A0);
\draw (C2) edge[out=-40, in=-40, arrow, in looseness=1.6] node[pos=0.85, below]{7D} (A1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used looseness for another similar drawing and I notice that the whole drawing starts to move outside the page. I have to draw a lot of them for an assignment, so I wonder if there is another way to do it.

Comment: @GeorgeSarantoglou There's a workaround for that mentioned here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373868/586