# What packages were used to produced this teaching diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar, teaching

I've been working on trying to develop a visual representation of the flow of ideas in one of my courses, and I came across this figure by Till Tantau

https://www.tcs.uni-luebeck.de/en/mitarbeiter/tantau/lehre/lectures/Algorithmendesign-Karte-2016.pdf

Does anyone know which packages were used to develop this? Since it's by Till, tikz is obviously involved, and the calendar package from tikz seems to be involved to get the calendar down the left hand side. But I can't figure out what packages were used to get the colored connections between the topic nodes unless they were all hard coded paths (which seems uncharacteristic).

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the connections are just edges with an angle in and out? See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/how-to-make-bend-lines-arrows-with-tikz.

Comment: Why do you think the paths are hard coded? As long as you make the texts nodes you can connect them with `\draw[blue] (node1) to[out=0,in=180] (node2);`, say.

Comment: It seems obvious to me that the proposed graphic was made with graphviz. It can be done with tikz but it might be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graphviz language  [Graphviz (examples)](https://graphviz.org/gallery/) and the [graphviz](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphviz) package.